# Renaming classOf in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm working on a customer-readable DSL for ScalaTest. At the moment I can write

```
feature("Admin Login") {
  scenario("Correct username and password") {
    given("user visits", classOf[AdminHomePage])
    then(classOf[SignInPage], "is displayed")
```

but this would read a lot better as

```
feature("Admin Login") {
  scenario("Correct username and password") {
    given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage])
    then(the[SignInPage], "is displayed")
```

Is there any way to

```
def the[T] =
```

to return `classOf[T]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do is just rename the method (which is defined in the `Predef` object) on import:

```
import Predef.{ classOf => the, _ }
```

Note that classOf won't work anymore if you rename it like this. If you still need it, also add this import:

```
import Predef.classOf;
```

For more renaming goodness see also:

- [How do I exclude/rename some classes from import in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871822/how-do-i-exclude-rename-some-classes-from-import-in-scala)
- [Unimporting in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668328/unimporting-in-scala)
- [what's wrong with renaming imported static functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650867/whats-wrong-with-renaming-imported-static-functions)
- [Scalada (beware, it its all pink o.o)](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/02/importing-all-classes-but-explicitly.html)

Comment: Nice, but this depends on clients of your library writing the right imports.

Comment: Well you'd have to import your own `the` implementation too, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, with something easy like `import mylib._`, without the need for an extra `import Predef.{ classOf => the, _ }`.

Comment: yes but there is a big difference between telling your users 'just import xxx._' and 'import xxx._ and Predef.{ classOf => the, _ } and if you still need it Predef.classOf'

Comment: @x3ro Good point about the automatic package import. I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744768/can-i-import-from-multiple-packages-all-at-once-in-scala), and for lack of answers I've concluded that such a thing is not possible at the time (2.9).

Answer (score 17):

You could try this:

```
def the[T: ClassManifest]: Class[T] =
  classManifest[T].erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
```

The notation `[T: ClassManifest]` is a *[context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala)* and is equivalent to:

```
def the[T](implicit classManifest: ClassManifest[T])
```

Implicit values for `Manifest[T]` and `ClassManifest[T]` are automatically filled in by the compiler (if it can reify the type parameter passed to the method) and give you run-time information about `T`: `ClassManifest` gives just its erasure as a `Class[_]`, and `Manifest` additionally can inform you about a possible parametrization of `T` itself (e.g., if `T` is `Option[String]`, then you can learn about the `String` part, too).

Comment: Thank you - I have tried it, and it works! I have no idea what it does though - I've gone from being a big Java shark to a Scala minnow ;-)

Comment: @Duncan I've added a short explanation about context bounds and manifests.

Comment: You're a gent - yet more Scala'y goodness to digest. I haven't been this keen since I bought Coplien's book on C++